# Issue With a Summation Program in C++

Tags: c++, math

I'm a beginner C++ coder (and beginner at programming in general), and I seem to have run into a problem. My professor assigned me this project and I seem to have it down right for the most part, but I keep getting an answer that's wrong.  For my program, I keep getting **42** as the final answer when it should be **40** (entering **1.00** for b, **2.00** for l, and **0.01** for p). I'd appreciate any help, and thanks in advance for any suggestions or tips.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

  int main()
{
   double b, l, p, num, P;
   num = P = 0;

   cout << "Enter the net profit, net loss, and the probabilty "; 
   cout << "of the products being sold   respectively: ";
   cin  >> b >> l >> p;

   if (p <= 0 || p >= 1)
   {
       cout << "\n";
       cout << "The probability is either too large or small. " << endl;
       cout << "Please try again." << endl;
   }

   else 
   {   
       cout << "\n";  
       while( (b / (b + l)) > P)
       {
          P += (p * pow((1-p),num));
          num++;
       }

       cout << "It is optimal to order "; 
       cout << num + 1 << " products. " << endl;
   }

  system("PAUSE");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose with more descriptive variable names and some better formatting...

Comment: I strongly recommend you ALWAYS put braces around the bodies of loops and ifs, even when they're only one line long.

Comment: Try printing the value of `P` each time through the `while` loop, it should be illuminating.

Comment: What does this calculation represent, and why should f(1.0, 2.0, 0.01)=40?

Comment: `double netProfit, netLoss, probability, itemCount, whateverBigPRepresents` is helpful.  A little bit of extra typing, a lot of extra readability.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and suggestions. It's supposed to calculate how many items are optimal to order, given the net profit (p) or net loss (l) for how many units are left unsold. The actual summation should be equal to 39, then adding 1 to it should give me 40.

Comment: May try posting the question to Math.StackExchange, and see if any of those math-heads can translate that formula to English for you and see if what you have is right or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim to understand your application but just looking at the structure of the calculation, could it be that the value of P is left behind by one "turn" when comparing to the ratio, b / (b + l)?

If so then adding an update to P before entering the while loop does the trick, i.e., insert the P calculation, P(i = 0) = p, once prior to while.  So for clarity from "else" down I used the code:

```
else
    {
        cout << "\n";
        P = p; // added this line: P(i=0) = p
        while(b / (b + l) > P) {
            P += p * pow((1 - p),num);
            num++;
        }
        cout << "It is optimal to order ";
        cout << num + 1 << " products. " << endl;
    }
```

which gives the output:

```
It is optimal to order 40 products.
```

This of course may not be the real source of the error but might at least give you something extra to think about.

Comment: @aNYthing24: Ok glad it helped but make sure and work through all of the terms, I would hate for the answer to be just coincidentally right.  I also just took a look at your application notes, with num = 0, it is sufficient to simply write P = p (P(i=0) = p, instead of P += (p * pow((1-p),num))).  It seems that the zero-th term may have been left out, I just edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but that does seem like a cleaner implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The math for the answer is sound given the algorithm. Are you sure the answer is 40? On the last line you take `num` and add `1` giving you `42`. Are you sure it's not minus 1? I agree with some of nhgrif's comments on readability, but because you are new to this I'd let it slide for now. I'm more concerned with why or why not that `num + 1` should be there in your cout. The program, as far as I can tell, is working exactly as intended.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I tried minus 1 initially, and my professor said I should not be doing that to arrive at the answer. Here's the problem if you're interested: [link](http://i.imgur.com/AHqu3kb.png)